# Об употреблении слова "и" и словосочетаний "друг за другом", "один за другим"

Tags: семантика

Предположим на столике лежат туз, король, дама, валет.

Верно ли, что:

- указание "Возьми туза и короля." означает указание "Возьми друг за другом туза и короля.",
- указание "Возьми туза и короля." означает указание "Возьми один за другим туза и короля."?

Comment: Диссертацию пишете? А как называется тема и можно ли отвечающим рассчитывать на соавторство?

Answer (score 5):

Вы можете взять туза и короля, как считаете нужным. Можете один за другим, а можете одновременно. Разницы в семантике Ваших предложений не вижу. Большой вопрос: а Вы сами не знаете ответы на свои вопросы или притворяетесь?